# Can an abelian group have a minimal group topology?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

In the abstract of [this paper](http://65.54.113.26/Publication/16030379/atoms-and-antiatoms-in-the-lattice-of-group-topologies), it is said that a minimal group topology on an abelian group is not Hausdorff.

Suppose $G$ is an abelian group and $\mathcal T$ is a minimal group topology on $G$ and let $N$ be the intersection of all neighborhoods of the identity element and let $\pi: G\to \frac{G}{N}$ be defined by $\pi(x)=Nx$. Then the set of all $\pi[F]$ where $F$ is a neighborhood of the identity element of $G$ is base of neighborhoods for a Hausdorff group topology on $\frac{G}{N}$ which has to be minimal. But $\frac{G}{N}$ is abelian and by the claim above cannot have a minimal Hausdorff group topology. Therefore an abelian group cannot have a minimal group topology.

Where am I wrong in this reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper that you mentioned is referring to a theorem proved by D. Remus in his dissertation:

> **Theorem:** If $G$ is abelian and $\tau$ is a minimal group topology on $G$, then there exists a subgroup $N$ such that $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ($p$ prime) and $\{N\}$ is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of $e$ in $\tau$.

Note that the only group topologies in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ are the discrete and the indiscrete topologies, so there is in fact a Hausdorff minimal group topology on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. But according to the theorem, these are the only examples of such a thing.

I don't have access to Remus' dissertation but I believe his article *On the structure of the lattice of group topologies*, Results Math. 6 (1983), presents the same results without the proofs. In this article he writes:

> ...the following results are proved for abelian groups...
>   The atoms of $Tg(G)$, are the topologies induced by normal subgroups $N$ for which the factor group $G/N$ is a simple finite group.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with the reasoning? The claim is not exact?

Comment: Yes, I would say that.

Comment: Do you have the exact version of the theorem in Remus' dissertation? (probably it is German?)

Comment: @user47958, I added a bit on this.

Comment: thanks. There is a simple proof for $|G|>2^{|\Bbb N|}$. So I wanted to be sure if it is correct for $|G|\le 2^{|\Bbb N|}$